# DSpace - OAI-PMH - Pagination

Tags: pagination, dspace, oai-pmh

I would like to illustrate a problem with the pagination of the results of the **OAI-PMH Data Provider of DSpace**.

Let's assume that I display the first page of results of a specific type, in the context the **Identifiers**.

The URL of the request ends as shown here:

**".../oaidl.jsp?verb=&ListIdentifiers&metadataPrefix=pico"**

Until here, no problem. However, when selecting the **Show More** button, using exactly the Resumption Token indicated at the end of the first request response:

**".../oaidl.jsp?verb=ListIdentifiers&resumptionToken=9999-12-31|1753-01-01|null|pico|982|2019-03-02T14%3A29%3A11Z"**

I get an error page with the following message:

**"XML interpretation error: no root element found..."**

Can you tell me my mistake and, if possible, how can I solve it?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of DSpace are you running?  The reference implementation at demo.dspace.org has a different url pattern than your example.

http://demo.dspace.org/oai/request?verb=Identify

Comment: Hi terrywb, I run version 4.1.
"oaidl.jsp" is a custom JSP that launches the request starting with "verb" parameter.